# How to pass id to another controller function in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I need find relevant vehicle id and update some column values. I have following link to some  form.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{route('payments.payment',$vehicles->id)}}" role="button">Go Premium</a>
```

now I have following form in payment.blade.php

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('add-order')}}">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input type="hidden" id="adtype" name="adtype" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

now I need update vehicles table adtype values from 0 to 1 when click submit button of above form. I have following addorder function in PController,

```
public function addOrder(Request $request)
{
    $vehicle = Vehicle::find($id);
    $vehicle->adtype = $request->input('adtype');
    $vehicle->save();
}
```

and route is this,

```
Route::post('add-order', 'PController@addOrder');
```

but I got following error,

> ```
>  ErrorException
>     Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\PController::addOrder()
> ```

how can fix this problem?

**this is my route for payment.blade.php**

```
Route::get('myads/{id}/edit/payment', function(){
    return view('payments.payment');
})->name('payments.payment');
```

Comment: Are the classes `PaymentController`, you mentioned, and `PController` in your code, one and the same?

Comment: yes it is same PController is here sorry for that

Comment: `$id` is undefined in the scope of your method. I am not familiar with Laravel but you probably need to add it to your route if it is part of the url and inject it in your method as a parameter.

Comment: how can I add vehicle id to my route?

Comment: Maybe you can find something useful here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39931238/how-to-pass-variable-from-one-controller-to-another-controller-in-laravel

Comment: No, any solutions?